# Separable Solutions vs Integrating Factors

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am looking to better understand the key differences between these two methods of solving ODEs. I know they are very different, but I will give an example to show what I am a bit confused about.

For example, in one of my previous problems I had $$\frac{dQ}{dt}=3-0.7Q$$

Now, when I first saw this, It appeared to be linear to me. I thought maybe the best way to solve it would be to rewrite it as $$\frac{dQ}{dt}+0.7Q=3$$ and then use the 0.7 to solve for the integrating factor.

However, I was told that the correct answer is to look for separable solutions. Which I also understand how to do. But I am just a bit worried that I will try to solve something by using integrating factors when separation of variables should be used.

Is this the case? How can I know?

Thank you all!

Comment: The variables are only seperable without a constant: $dQ/dt=-0.7Q\Rightarrow \frac{1}{Q}dQ=-0.7dt$ Integrate both sides and solve for Q. In general you can apply the method of variation of parameter: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variation_of_parameters#First_order_equation

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite follow what you mean. Are you saying it can be done one the equation above?

Comment: It´s only the first step. Have you ever heard of the method of variation of parameters ?

Comment: I don't think so, is it something I should be aware of? It is the first week of intro to ODE course

Comment: I think so. 1. You can read the linked wiki-article. 2. Have you solved the homogenous equation ?

Comment: See the answer. The method of variation of parameter is not necessary.

Comment: Hi, thanks yes I did solve it that way, I am more asking IF / Why we cannot do integrating factors

Comment: See the answer again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least three methods can be applied successfully to this equation!

Separating variables is perfectly valid:

$\frac {dQ}{dt}=3-0.7Q$

$\int\frac 1 {3-0.7Q}dQ=\int dt$

$\frac 1 {-0.7} \log\left(3-0.7Q\right)=t+c$

$\log\left(3-0.7Q\right)=-0.7 t+c'$

$3-0.7Q=Ae^{-0.7 t}$

$0.7Q=3-Ae^{-0.7 t}$

$Q=\frac {30} 7-A'e^{-0.7 t}$

Integrating factor is also valid:

$\frac {dQ}{dt}+0.7Q=3$

$\frac {dQ}{dt}e^{0.7t}+0.7Qe^{0.7t}=3e^{0.7t}$

$\frac {d}{dt}\left(Qe^{0.7t}\right)=3e^{0.7t}$

$Qe^{0.7t}=\frac{3}{0.7}e^{0.7t}+B$

$Q=\frac{3}{0.7}+\frac B {Qe^{0.7t}}$

$Q=\frac{30}{7}+ B Qe^{-0.7t}$

Solve first as homogenous DE and then find the particular integral...

Consider first $\frac {dQ}{dt}=-0.7Q$

This has well-known general solution $Q_{general}=De^{-0.7t}$

The non-homogenous part is a constant term, so we have $Q_{trial}(t)=k$ with $\frac d {dt}Q_{trial}(t)=0$.

Need $Q_{trial}$ to satisfy the differential equation.

$0=3-0.7k$

$k=\frac {30} 7$

Combine $Q=Q_{general}+Q_{trial}=De^{-0.7t}+\frac {30} 7$

They all give the same solution - you just have to decide which is more efficient.

With other DEs, maybe only one (or none!) of these methods will be applicable.

Comment: Thanks, so I am wondering if you know, if an ODE is linear and separation of variables is valid, will method of IF always also be?

Comment: Good question. Try to find a counterexample.

Comment: A linear first order ODE, constant coefficients or not, will always let you use integrating factors.

Answer (score 1):

A separable equation has the form 
$$Q'(t)=f(t)g(Q)$$
while a linear equation has the form
$$Q'(t)+h(t)Q(t)=i(t).$$

When $g(Q)=aQ+b$ is a linear function, you get a separable and linear equation
$$Q'(t)-aQ=f(t)b,$$
and when $i(t)=0$ you get a linear and separable equation
$$Q'(t)=-h(t)Q(t).$$
As you see, there is an overlap between the domain of application of the resolution methods.

Let us compare:

- $g(Q)=aQ+b$, separable:

$$\frac{Q'(t)}{aQ+b}=f(t)\to\frac1a{\ln(aQ+b)}=\int f(t)\,dt.$$

- $g(Q)=aQ+b$, linear: the integrand factor is $e^{-at}$, and

$$Q'(t)-aQ=f(t)b\to e^{-at}Q(t)=\int e^{-at}f(t)b\,dt.$$

The best option depends on the shape of the function $f$.

- $i(t)=0$, separable:

$$Q'(t)=-h(t)Q(t)\to\ln(Q(t))=-\int h(t)\,dt.$$

- $i(t)=0$, linear: the integrand factor is $e^{\int h(t)\,dt}$:

$$Q'(t)+h(t)Q(t)=0\to Q(t)e^{\int h(t)\,dt}=C.$$

The two approaches are equivalent.

Comment: Thanks, this is also very helpful